# structuremap Buildup() a user control

Tags: user-controls, dependency-injection, structuremap

2 questions here.  I have a page that I already use setter DI to insert a service layer using the following snippet from another post.

```
var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
var page = application.Context.CurrentHandler as Page;
if (page == null) return;
    ObjectFactory.BuildUp(page);
```

How would I do the same for a user control that sits on the same page and also needs a service layer injected?

Also it seems redundant/inefficent to have multiple instances of the service layer existing for just one call to a page, is there a better design?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose this must be horribly apparent and a bad question in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I was asking the question poorly.

```
protected override void OnInit (System.EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnInit (e);
    IoC.BuildUp (this);
  }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Is this override in the usercontrol itself? Tried this and still not working.